# Postman with Pre-request Scripts: "Error: Parse Error: Header overflow"

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I was having this problem only when running requests for a local application with some Pre-request Scripts:

`Error: Parse Error: Header overflow`

The Postman version was: v7.25.0.

PS: For the same request for my server application, I wasn't received any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using a `MacOS Catalina 10.15.5` with a `rails 6.0.3.1` and `puma 4.3.5` on localhost and `nginx` on the server.

The problem for me was the `scout_apm` that includes a huge header. I ended up by removing this using `SCOUT_DEV_TRACE=false`

https://docs.scoutapm.com/#ruby-devtrace

Comment: You deserve a medal! I was fighting against this for a couple of days without any luck. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem just to upgrade Postman version:

- Postman from v7.25.0 to v7.26.0

Other important information about my current environment:

- Node v14.3.0
- NPM v6.14.5

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to set environment variable and launch Postman again:

`NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=16384`

In case your header is really huge, maybe you want to even use:

`NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=65536`

Source:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8656